# In welchem Teil Deutschlands fragt man "Was soll der Name?"

Tags: meaning, phrase, colloquial, regional

> Dein Name ist Campino. Was soll der Name?
>
> Der Name bedeutet Bauer auf Plattdeutsch

Ich möchte wissen, in welchem Teil des Landes man diesen Ausdruck verwendet. Wenn ich mich nicht irre, fragte mich das eine Person, die aus Berlin kommt. Ich frage mich, ob dieser Ausdruck in ganz Deutschland benutzt wird.

Comment: Habe ich noch nie gehört. Recht unklar, die Frage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dieser Ausdruck ist eine Variation für ***Was bedeutet (der Name)?***.

Die Wendung wird allgemein am häufigsten wohl in Form von *Was soll das?* als Kurzform für *Was soll das bewirken/werden/bedeuten?* verwendet, wobei *das* meist eine Aktion oder Tat des Angesprochenen bezeichnet.

Soweit ich es beurteilen kann, wird das in ganz Deutschland verwendet, ist aber kein neutraler Ausdruck, sondern drückt in der Regel ein leichtes bis mäßiges Missfallen aus.

> A) [nimmt, ohne zu fragen, ein Gummibärchen aus Bs Tüte]
>
> B) Was soll das?

B möchte wissen, warum A so handelt, und gleichzeitig ausdrücken, dass B es bevorzugen würde, wenn A *nicht* so handeln würde.

Bei Deinem konkreten Beispiel könnte der Fragende also zum Ausdruck bringen wollen, dass er den Namen z. B. albern findet, aber trotzdem die Hintergründe dazu kennen will. Je nach Beziehung zwischen den beiden Parteien könnte der Ausdruck aber auch flappsig-neutral oder stichelnd gemeint sein.

Comment: "Was soll der Name?" würde bei mir ohne viel weiteren Kontext wahrscheinlich nur einen ratlosen Blick auslösen. "Was soll das?" hat, wie du richtig schreibst, die Bedeutung von "Was hast du dir dabei gedacht?" und das ergibt für mich bei einem Namen, den man sich normalerweise nicht selbst ausgesucht hat, keinen rechten Sinn.

Comment: Künstlernamen sucht man sich für gewöhnlich selbst aus, und um einen solchen geht es doch wohl.

Comment: @userunknown: Exakt, und unter der Frage "Was soll der Name?" würde ich dementsprechend keine Frage nach der *Bedeutung* des Namens verstehen, sondern vielmehr eine nach der *Begründung* (wieso überhaupt dieser Name verwendet wird).